# How to remove multi-line string in lua

Tags: string, lua, multiline

How do I make a multiline string into a single line string in lua?

I've tried this:

```
function removeMultilines(str)
    return str:gsub("\n")
end
```

But it doesn't work.

So basically, I would want to turn `str1` into `str2`

```
local str1 = [[Hey,
how are you today?
Whats your name?]]

local str2 = "Hey, how are you today? Whats your name?"
```

Does anyone know how I can possibly approach that? Any help is welcome, just comment :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lua 5.3 Reference Manual: string.gsub (s, pattern, repl [, n])](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub)

> Returns a copy of s in which all (or the first n, if given) occurrences of the pattern (see §6.4.1) have been replaced by a replacement string specified by repl, which can be a string, a table, or a function. gsub also returns, as its second value, the total number of matches that occurred. The name gsub comes from Global SUBstitution.

Covered at the bottom of [Programming in Lua: 20.1 – Pattern-Matching Functions](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html) here is one of the examples:

```lua
s = string.gsub("Lua is cute", "cute", "great")
print(s)         --> Lua is great
```

Proper use of `string.gsub` requires the string, a pattern `"\n"` and the value replace the match with `" "`.

```lua
local str2 = str1:gsub("\r?\n", " ") --`\n` signifies the newline character
                                     --`\r?` add some handling for different line endings
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [string.gmatch](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch), though `string.gsub` is better suited for it replacement.

Proper use, for your case, could look like:

```lua
function removeMultilines(str)
    local lines = str:gmatch("([^\r\n]+)\r?\n?")
    local output = lines()

    for line in lines do
        output = output .. " " .. line
    end

    print(output)
    return output
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str:gsub("\n"," ")` in `removeMultilines`.

Use `str:gsub("\n+"," ")` to collapse blank lines.